# iOS 5 NSJSONSerialization Error

Tags: cocoa, ios5, nsjsonserialization

I am attempting to parse a local JSON file using NSJSONSerialization. Works fine on iOS 6, but on iOS 5 I get an error  `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Duplicate key for object around character 1515.)` How could it be that there is a duplicate key on iOS 5 but not on iOS 6? I've tried various JSON validation services all of which agree that it is a valid JSON file. I have read that \ characters can cause this, but my JSON contains no \ characters verified using Find. What can I do to make this JSON deserialize on iOS 5?

Comment: Btw, if it turns out that you cannot persuade the web service to avoid duplicate keys on JSON Objects, you may resort to a third party library. There are a few, but I can tell only one library which has for sure an option that controls duplicate key behavior: [JPJson](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/JPJson). Disclosure: Well, I'm the author ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate keys are not invalid as per [RFC 4672](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). In **§2.2. Objects**,  it merely states:

"... The names within an object SHOULD be unique."

The meaning of the word "SHOULD" is defined in [RFC 2119](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119):

> 3. SHOULD   This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there
>    may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
>    particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
>    carefully weighed before choosing a different course.

That is, `NSJSONSerialization` behaves still "correct" in iOS 6.

IMO, the behavior regarding duplicate keys should be a configurable option:

1. Silently accept duplicate keys and potentially omit the duplicated entries in the generated representation, if this is an associative container with unique keys (which is true for a NSDictionary), or
2. log a warning to the error console, or
3. signal an error.

Comment: Makes sense, I suppose in iOS 5 duplicate keys were regarded as invalid. I found the offending keys and changed them and it now it deserializes correctly on iOS 5.

Comment: Fine, duplicate key are calling for trouble. Better avoid them.